# How to turn on intelligent code completion for Expression Editor in Informatica PowerCenter Express/Developer?

Tags: autocomplete, informatica-powercenter

I wonder whether it is possible to use Eclipse or IntelliSense-like intelligent code completion for Expression Editor in Informatica PowerCenter Express/Developer. Can you tell me whether it's possible and if so, can you tell me how to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible. Anyway, the list of functions Expression Editor supports is pretty limited and are listed on the left pane from where you can easily import.